# Connect appengine with cakephp

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, cakephp

I'm thinking in create a webapplication with cakephp but consuming python's appengine webservice. But, to install cakephp etc, I need to configure the database. Appengine uses another kind of datastorage, with is different from mysql, etc.

I was thinking in store the data in appengine, and using the python webservices, and with the cakephp application comunicating with the webservice, for insert and retrieve data.

Is there any good resource for this, or is it unpossible.

**Obs: also opened for a possibility for developing the webapplicaiton completely in python running in appengine. If anyone has a good resource.**

Thanks.

Comment: This is an exceedingly general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that CakePHP is a MVC framework that's very similar to django, which is included in app engine for python. I'm not sure why you would want to store your data in google app engine, unless you're dealing with an extremely large amount of data, in which case you're likely comfortable enough working in python to just make the app work entirely on GAE.

See the official docs for more info:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should try different solution: http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Comment: why do you think its a better solution?

Comment: coz you can use simpledb "as is". in this case (php framework) you  must write some proxy service in python if you want to use google datastorage.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is run your CakePHP app on a standard LAMP web host and access the GAE Data Store through [a REST or RPC web service.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/) This isn't such a bad idea if you already have a CakePHP front-end that deals with RPCs in the backend, but if your Cake app stores all it's Models in MySQL it could take considerable effort to adapt it.CakePHP Models abstract their storage method using the DataSource class. You might be able to find [a DataSource class that uses REST or RPC.](http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/06/01/rest-datasource-plugin-for-cakephp/) However, if you don't have a very considerable investment in CakePHP Controllers and Templates I would suggest simply building your app entirely in GAE

Answer (score 0):

You can not run PHP on GAE. If you run PHP somewhere, it is a bad architecture to go over the internet for your data. It will be slooooow and a nightmare to develop in.
You should store your data where you run your php, unless you must have a distributed, globally scaling architecture, which afaiu not the case.

Comment: This is not entirely true; you can run PHP on the JVM using App Engine's Java runtime, although it's hardly ideal.

Comment: Don't most MySQL queries go over the Internet anyway? Ideally to Database hosts in the same data center, but not necessarily

Comment: As Wooble said, this is not technically true. With the JVM, you can run PHP (eg: via Quercus), Ruby (eg: via JRuby), etc.

Comment: @jessehattabaugh: no way. You rarely go over the internet for your data. That is utterly inappropriate and is slooooow, especially considering latency. A data center or a server in the next rack connected over gigabit ethernet lan is not the internet.

Comment: App Engine now officially supports PHP. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php

Answer (score 0):

There's a detailed tutorial on getting CakePHP up using the PHP runtime that Google recently announced. http://aymanrb.blogspot.com/2013/05/cakephp-deployment-on-google-app-engine.html